# WordPress - How to add HTML in a tooltip with Bootstrap 4.5?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, tooltip

After browsing through quite a few topics on the web, I've come to ask directly because I haven't found an answer to my question.

On WordPress, I try to embed an HTML image in a tooltip on a link, but the whole HTML code of my page breaks.

In my `head`, I have the following JS script to activate the tooltips:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            html: true
        })
    })
</script>
```

In my WordPress page, I have the following HTML code:

```html
<li><a href="/jeux/tr1/solution/item1/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='/img/jeux/tr1/solution/001.png' alt=''>">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/jeux/tr1/solution/item2/">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/jeux/tr1/solution/item3/">Item 3</a></li>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

The end of the code of the first `li` is not interpreted, and the browser (Firefox in this case) displays Item 2 directly with the bugged Item 1 in the tooltip.

You can take a look directly here: https://www.tombraidercie.com/public-playground/

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found the answer!

There is a native function (wptexturize) in Wordpress that transforms certain characters into "smart" characters. And a little sentence [in their doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/) explains that the "code within certain HTML blocks are skipped."

So if you have a Wordpress site and want to embed HTML code in your tooltips, remove this native function by adding this line to your theme's functions.php file.

```php
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to enable `"data-html=true"`?

This is from a current project:

```
<button type="button" class="classes" data-toggle="popover" title="Title" data-content="Content <a href='#'>> Link</a>" data-html="true"></button>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't help. :(

Everything after the data-title attribute is not interpreted and appears on the screen: https://i.imgur.com/WISLUUZ.png

Is your current project on WordPress?  I think there is a problem with WordPress.

Comment: Send your code here

Comment: You can take a look here: https://www.tombraidercie.com/public-playground/ - Move your mouse over "Sub-Item B" to see the unexpected behavior. Thanks for your help!